# Pass path with spaces to Fortran application

Tags: c#, path, fortran

I have an old Fortran application to which I'd like to pass a path to a file.

Unfortunately my path contains spaces. I cannot change the file path but I'd like to process the file with my Fortran application.

The Fotran app doesn't work even if I pass the path from C# with quotes (e.g. "C:\Users[username]\Desktop\Example Path\example_file.dat").

This is my code:

```
 ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
 {
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = @"/c <program_name> <file path with spaces>",
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\<exe_location>\",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
 };
```

This is the error, stopping at the first space:

`Non existent file: <file p`

It's the same if I try to pass the path via command line.

Is there some escape sequence I'm missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: pass how? Command line?  Show how the fortran is processing the input.

Comment: Sorry @agentp, I added more details in the original post.

Comment: Do you literally have those angle brackets?  Anyway I bet the total path length is the problem. The old code likely has some hard coded string length for the name

Comment: Oh, you are right. I tested by trying to open the file first from C:\ then going deeper. It hangs right at 65 characters, spaces are not a problem, length is. If you post it as an answer I'll happily accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `cmd.exe` instead of calling the Fortran executable directly?